# Zend authentication Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, zend-framework2, slim, zend-framework3

I've been encountering an intermittent issue with session storage in Zend framework.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: PHP Error: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php:383 
Stack trace: #0 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(383): {closure}(2, 'Cannot use a sc...', 'C:\\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\\...', 383, Array) 
#1 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(468): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->setMetadata('_REQUEST_ACCESS...', 1499126021.8803) 
#2 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(55): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->setRequestAccessTime(1499126021.8803) 
#3 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\SessionManager.php(124): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->init(Array) 
#4 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionMa in C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php on line 383

Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: PHP Error: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php:411 Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(2, 'array_key_exist...', 'C:\\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\\...', 411, Array) 
#1 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(411): array_key_exists('_REQUEST_ACCESS...', 0) 
#2 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(457): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->getMetadata('_REQUEST_ACCESS...') 
#3 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php(213): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->getRequestAccessTime() #4 C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\SessionManager.php(205): Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage->fromArray(Array) 
#5 [internal function]: Zend\Session\Sess in C:\MYCOMPANY_WebApps\CEC\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php on line 411
```

Once I clear my cookies, I can login again without any issues, and the error won't reoccur for some time.

My Slim middleware.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use JeremyKendall\Password\PasswordValidator;
use JeremyKendall\Slim\Auth\Adapter\Db\PdoAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap as LdapAdapter;
use JeremyKendall\Slim\Auth\Bootstrap;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;
use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

require_once __DIR__."/../src/acl.php";

// Configure Slim Auth components
global $app;
$c = $app->getContainer();
$db = $c['db']['db'];

// Configure the authentication middleware
if (empty($c['ldap'])) {
    // Use the PdoAdapter (local users database) when there is no LDAP config available
    $validator = new PasswordValidator();
    $adapter = new PdoAdapter($db, 'users', 'username', 'password', $validator);
}
else {
    $opts = $c['ldap'];
    $adapter = new LdapAdapter(array(array(
        'host' => $opts['host'],
        'username' => $opts['username'],
        'password' => $opts['password'],
        'bindRequiresDn' => $opts['bindRequiresDn'],
        'accountDomainName' => $opts['accountDomainName'],
        'baseDn' => $opts['baseDn']
    )));
}

$acl = new Acl();

$options = array('remember_me_seconds' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                'name'                => 'slim-auth-impl');

$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig($options);
$sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
$sessionManager->rememberMe();
$storage = new SessionStorage(null, null, $sessionManager);

$authBootstrap = new Bootstrap($app, $adapter, $acl);
$authBootstrap->setStorage($storage);
$authBootstrap->bootstrap();

// Store the auth object in the the container, so it's available to the app
$c['auth'] = $app->auth;

?>
```

When I delve into the Zend libraries, I can see the following call fall over:

```
$this->setMetadata('_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME', $time);
```

which attempts to set the value of the `_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME` key in an array that doesn't exist:

```
$_SESSION['__ZF'][$key] = $value;
```

and subsequently, checks against this session array fail:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['__ZF'])) {
...
```

The application is using slim 3.8.1, as well as Bootstrap from jeremykendall/slim-auth 1.0.1.

This one has me a little stumped, since the errors seem to occur internally within the Zend libraries.

Any ideas how this error could be avoided?

**Edit:**

Encountered the error again and inserted some debugging.

The line in the middleware which causes the issue:

```
$storage = new SessionStorage(null, null, $sessionManager);
```

The session just contains:

```
array(1) {
  ["__ZF"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

In another browser, a working session looks like:

```
array(2) {
  ["__ZF"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME"]=>
    float(1513551496.9529)
  }
  ["Zend_Auth"]=>
  object(Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject)#98 (4) {
    ["storage":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["storage"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["username"]=>
        string(6) "myusername"
        ["role"]=>
        string(6) "member"
      }
    }
    ["flag":protected]=>
    int(2)
    ["iteratorClass":protected]=>
    string(13) "ArrayIterator"
    ["protectedProperties":protected]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "storage"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "flag"
      [2]=>
      string(13) "iteratorClass"
      [3]=>
      string(19) "protectedProperties"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that Jeremy's library is not maintained, so it could be an issue with that.

Comment: @AndrewSmith Yes, I really hope not. The documentation confidently states that it is "production ready". The error occurs within Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session somewhere, but the auth bootstrap Bootstrap may well break the session somehow. Very difficult to debug.